# Where to collect data from the web in Rails 4 MCV

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm building a rails application where I parse some html data on the web and then save it in my database, the data is saved in multiple models though. I'm currently doing that in the controller, but I'm not sure where I should do it in the MCV model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it well, the work of the controllers is get the data from users, aply some logic and save it on database.

The model work is to ensure that data is correct and understanable and work as gateway between ruby classes and database tables.

Here you can find more information about MVC

http://projectmanagementdud.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/model-view-controller-mvc-simply.html

In your case you're parsing data in your controller and this controller save data on multiple models, this is accepted, one controller is not obligated to interactue only with one model, if isn't, save data in the models with the same action will be impossible, a good practice is to choose this controller with wisdom :).